# Get Opportunity with Opportunity Line Items

Tags: api, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

How can I use the salesforce api to get a list of opportunities such that each opportunity contains it's opportunity line items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the SOQL it would be something like this-

[Select Id, (Select Id From OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity]

Once you get that, you would have to loop through a list of items under each Opportunity record. Hope this answers your question.